# Add attachment on mas mailing

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

So this is my mass mailing code for sale orders. But I just missing here one thing. it's that it should add a sale order report that I created to each of SO I'm generating e-mail for. any suggestions how can I make this work?

```xml
<data>
            <act_window name="Mass Sale Order Email"
                    res_model="mail.compose.message"
                    src_model="sale.order"
                    view_mode="form"
                    multi="True"
                    target="new"
                    key2="client_action_multi"
                    id="action_send_mass_sale_order"
                    context="{
                                'default_composition_mode': 'mass_mail',
                                'default_email_to': '{($object.email or \'\')|safe}',
                                'mass_mark_sale_order_as_sent': True,
                                'default_model': 'sale.order',
                            }"
                    />
        </data>
```

```py
 class MailComposeMessage(models.TransientModel):
        _inherit = 'mail.compose.message'

        @api.multi
        def send_mail(self, auto_commit=False):
            context = self._context
            sale_order = self.env['sale.order']
            sale_order_ids = context.get('active_ids')
            if context.get('mass_mark_sale_order_as_sent') and \
                    context.get('default_model') == 'sale.order':
                for order in sale_order.browse(sale_order_ids):
                    order.sent = True
            return super(MailComposeMessage, self).send_mail(auto_commit=auto_commit)
```

```xml
<report 
     id="report_htp_sale_order"
        string="Htp Sale Order"
         model="sale.order"
         name="config_htp.htp_sale_order"
         rml="config_htp/report/htp_sale_order.ods"
         menu="True"
   />


<record model="ir.actions.report.xml" id="report_htp_sale_order">
     <field name="report_type">aeroo</field>
     <field name="parser_loc">config_htp/report/htp_sale_order.pyc</field>
     <field name="tml_Source">file</field>
     <field name="parser_state">loc</field>
     <field name="out_format" ref="report_aeroo.report_mimetypes_ods_ods"/>
    <field name="in_format">oo-ods</field>
     <field name="auto" eval="True" />
 </record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In context, we need to add a default template and in that template, we can choose what report we want to attach to it.

```
'default_use_template': True,
'default_template_id': ref('sale.email_template_edi_sale'),
```